# What's the third wire on a piezo buzzer?

Tags: piezo-buzzer

Most piezos I've seen have just two connections, but this type has three.
[image: 3-wire piezo]
What's the third wire for?

Comment: I accepted stevenvh's answer because it makes it clear to me. Don't let this stop you from posting other answers, however, possibly giving more detail. I might change my mind :-)

Comment: It's a good answer. Nice and clear and to the point.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

They're called **self drive** types, and they're meant to be used as part of the oscillator:

[image: piezo self-drive]

The piezo effect works both ways: if you apply a voltage the piezo stretches, but also if it stretches it creates a voltage. This principle is used to create a feedback signal which drives the oscillator.
The advantage of the self drive is that it will automagically work at its **resonance frequency**, where it produces the loudest sound. In 2-wire circuits the oscillator's frequency is independent of the piezo's resonance frequency, and it's the designer who has to make that they're close.

For the piezo of your picture:

> "G" = black
>   "M" = red
>   "F" = blue

(I guess `M`, `F` and `G` stand for `Main`, `Feedback` and `Ground`, resp. CMIIW)

Comment: I found a 3 pin piezo puzzer in a smoke detector and was wondering how it works (and why it's there). Now that you say  it allows to produce the loudest sound, it makes sense...

Comment: Since the device optimizes its own sound and driving frequency, this also means you can lower the sound frequency by increasing the mass of the driver, perhaps by attaching a small weight (a bb) to the back of the device, the brass side.  This might also make it more efficient.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a good in-depth explanation of buzzers including self-driven ones + some usefull schematics:  [Piezoelectric Sound Components Application Manual](http://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/sound/p37e.ashx) (812kb).

Excerpt (from p.5):

> **Self Drive**
>
> Method Fig. 9 shows a typical application of the self drive
>   method. The piezoelectric diaphragm provided with feedback electrode
>   shown in Fig. 9 (i) is involved in the closed loop of a Hartley types
>   oscillation circuit. When the frequency is closed to the resonant
>   frequency, the circuit satisfies oscillating conditions, and the
>   piezoelectric diaphragm is driven with the oscillating frequency. Fig.
>   9 (ii) shows a simple oscillating circuit consisting of one transistor
>   and three resistors. In general, the node support shown in Fig. 3 (a)
>   is popular in the self drive method. Proper resonance of the
>   piezoelectric diaphragm by the node support provides stable
>   oscillation with high mechanical Qm of vibration but also a single
>   high pressure tone.
>
> [image]

Comment: I agree, it does, but linking to a pdf with all the information makes for a bad answer. Please include some of the relevant information in your answer text.

Comment: @hurufu  Welcome to EE.SE.  There is a slight problem with answers, which primarily consists of link to an external page (so called *link-only answer*).  If that page moves in the future, then the link dies, and the answer becomes largely useless.  So, include an abstract (or excerpt, or synopsis) along with the link.

Comment: this helps a lot to me and make this circuit clear~